# A single word for "that of"?

Tags: single-word-requests

The use of "that of" I'm referring to has the following usage:

> My work is similar to that of Jack.

Is there a single word to represent the "that of" part?

Note we have "thereof" for "of that" and "whereof" for "of which".

Comment: Please use `> ` rather than `\`` `\`` for quotes - http://english.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 3):

Here is a half-word solution for that particular usage:

```
My work is similar to Jack's
```

It's also how I would communicate that message as a native speaker.

The origin sentence is rather awkward in common speech.

Comment: What if Jack is a really long thing? Such as "The state of Hawaii"?